# Conversion failed from varchar to int, ado.net

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, winforms

I'm working with sql databases via ado.net in c# and I'm trying to pass the following update command:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE VehicleContract SET regNr='@reg', assoc_id='@assort', percentage='@perc', vehicleType='@type', trailerNr='@trailer' WHERE contractId='@id'";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

id is in int. I read it as an int. I even do a int.Parse(txtbox.text) and everything is fine. But then when I insert all the values in the boxes, press submit. I get the conversion error saying that it can't convert '@id' varchar to int... it makes no sense

Is there any specific thing I'm not doing right? Need any more details?

```
The whole code:
if (tbid.Text == "" || tbper.Text == "" || tbas.Text == "" || tbvt.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All fields must be filled ");
                return;
            }
            if (tbreg.Text == "" && tbtn.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill at least one from: Registration nr or trailer nr");
                return;
            }
            int id = 0;
            string reg = "";
            int assort = 0;
            int perc = 0;
            string type = "";
            int trailer = 0;
            try
            {
                id = int.Parse(tbid.Text);
                Console.Write(id);
                if (tbreg.Text != "")
                {
                    reg = tbreg.Text;
                }
                assort = int.Parse(tbas.Text);
                perc = int.Parse(tbper.Text);
                type = tbvt.Text;
                if (tbtn.Text != "")
                {
                    trailer = int.Parse(tbtn.Text);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("id, assoc, perc and trailer nr must be integers ");
                return;
            }
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;initial Catalog=Lab5;integrated security=true";
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE VehicleContract SET regNr='@reg', assoc_id='@assort', percentage='@perc', vehicleType='@type', trailerNr='@trailer' WHERE contractId='@id'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            if (reg == "")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", reg);
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assort", assort);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@perc", perc);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
            if (trailer == 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trailer", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trailer", trailer);
            }
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sdr);

            childgrid.DataSource = dt;
            sdr.Close();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: remove single quotes around @id and other parameters.

Comment: Don't put quotes around parameter names.  That turns them into literal strings whose values are the parameter names.  It's the equivalent of doing this in C# `int i = 5; int j = "i";`

Comment: You are right! Thank you!

Comment: I see you are using pass through sql with AddWithValue. This can sometimes interpret the incorrect datatype. It is best if you explicitly set your datatypes or switch to stored procedures. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1):

When you use `WHERE contractId='@id'` in a query you are comparing the int `contractId` column with the string `'@id'` value.

You need to use `WHERE contractId=@id`.

So remove single quotes around `@id` and other parameters.